# Azure SQL database snapshot

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have Azure SQL database.  Before updating it (schema) as part of a dev ops pipeline, I'd like to take a snapshot so should the worst happen I can roll back.

Imagine my dismay when I discovered that snapshots aren't available for Azure SQL database.

What's the best practice here?

Comment: Azure SQL database has the feature auto backup. If the the worst happen, you could run Point-in-time restore to roll back.

Answer (score 1):

The moral equivalent you can do in SQL Azure is:

- start an active geodr to the same region
- let it seed and catch up
- break the replication at the point to which you want the option to roll back in case of problems in your dev ops change.

This avoids the time to do a PITR restore (but you pay for the extra database for the duration it is alive).